# Modified function not working as intended without recursion

Tags: recursion

I have a recursive function which iterates though directory trees listing the file names located in them.

Here is the function:

```c
void WINAPI SearchFile(PSTR Directory)
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;

    char SearchName[1024],FullPath[1024];

    memset(SearchName,0,sizeof(SearchName));
    memset(&FindData,0,sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    sprintf(SearchName,"%s\\*",Directory);

    hFind=FindFirstFile(SearchName,&FindData);

    if(hFind!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        while(FindNextFile(hFind,&FindData))
        {
            if(FindData.cFileName[0]=='.')
            {
                continue;
            }
           
            memset(FullPath,0,sizeof(FullPath));
            sprintf(FullPath,"%s\\%s",Directory,FindData.cFileName);

            if(FindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
              MessageBoxA(NULL, FullPath, "Directory", MB_OK);
                SearchFile(FullPath);
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, FullPath, "File", MB_OK);
            }

        }

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

There are obviously differences between both functions but I don't understand what's making them act differently. Does anyone know why I am having this problem?

Comment: *I need to replace this with a single function that's not recursive* - if you want recursive file search - function for this must be recursive. you can not convert recursion for loop here. and unclear why  you at all want try this

Comment: I don't see any evidence of you pushing the search onto some kind of stack while iterating over search results, then beginning another search.  This is what you need to do if you want to emulate recursive calls.  When a search is complete, you should pop an item off the stack and continue that search.  When the search is complete and no searches remain on your stack, you're done.  Note that you can use a queue or other data structure instead of a stack to achieve different priority ordering of the sub-searches.

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to accept it if it does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fast understand error need look for line

```
        goto label;
        //SearchFile(FullPath);
```

at this point `hFind` containing valid data and `FindClose(hFind);` need be called for it. but after `goto label;` executed - your **overwrite** `hFind` with `hFind = FindFirstFile(SearchName, &FindData);` - so you already never close original `hFind`, never can return to iterate folder after such go to sub-folder. this is key point - need save original `hFind` before go to sub directory and restore it after. when you do recursive function call - this is done auto - because every sub directory in this case enumerated in self stack frame, which have separate `hFind`. this is native solution use recursion here.

but possible convert recursion to loop here because we call self always from the **single** place and as result to this **single** place. so we can not save return address in stack but do unconditional jump (goto) to known place.

then code have some extra errors, you never check for string buffers overflow, why 1024 as max length is hard-coded when file path can be up to 32768 chars, you not check for reparse point as result can enter to infinite loop, use `FindFirstFile` instead `FindFirstFileEx`, etc.

correct code for enumerate sub-folder in loop can be next

```
void DoEnum(PCWSTR pcszRoot)
{
    SIZE_T FileNameLength = wcslen(pcszRoot);

    // initial check for . and ..
    switch (FileNameLength)
    {
    case 2:
        if (pcszRoot[1] != '.') break;
    case 1:
        if (pcszRoot[0] == '.') return;
    }

    static const WCHAR mask[] = L"\\*";
    WCHAR FileName[MAXSHORT + 1];

    if (_countof(FileName) < FileNameLength + _countof(mask))
    {
        return;
    }

    ULONG dwError;
    HANDLE hFindFile = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData{};

    enum { MaxDeep = 0x200 };
    //++ stack
    HANDLE hFindFileV[MaxDeep];
    PWSTR pszV[MaxDeep];
    char prefix[MaxDeep+1];
    //--stack

    ULONG Level = MaxDeep;
    memset(prefix, '\t', MaxDeep);
    prefix[MaxDeep] = 0;

    PWSTR psz = FileName;

    goto __enter;

__loop:

    hFindFile = FindFirstFileEx(FileName, FindExInfoBasic, &FindData, FindExSearchNameMatch, 0, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);

    if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do 
        {
            pcszRoot = FindData.cFileName;

            // skip . and ..
            switch (FileNameLength = wcslen(pcszRoot))
            {
            case 2:
                if (pcszRoot[1] != '.') break;
            case 1:
                if (pcszRoot[0] == '.') continue;
            }

            if (FindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((SIZE_T)(FileName + _countof(FileName) - psz) < FileNameLength + _countof(mask))
                {
                    continue;
                }
__enter:
                memcpy(psz, pcszRoot, (1 + FileNameLength) * sizeof(WCHAR));

                if (FindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)
                {
                    DbgPrint("%sreparse point: <%S>\n", prefix + Level, pcszRoot);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Level)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%s<%S>\n", prefix + Level, psz);

                        hFindFileV[--Level] = hFindFile;
                        pszV[Level] = psz;

                        memcpy(psz += FileNameLength, mask, sizeof(mask));

                        psz++;
                        goto __loop;
__return:

                        *--psz = 0;
                        psz = pszV[Level];
                        hFindFile = hFindFileV[Level++];

                        DbgPrint("%s</%S>\n", prefix + Level, psz);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DbgPrint("%s[%u%u] %S\n", prefix + Level, FindData.nFileSizeLow, FindData.nFileSizeHigh, pcszRoot);
            }

            if (!hFindFile)
            {
                // top level exit
                return ;
            }

        } while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindData));

        if ((dwError = GetLastError()) == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            dwError = NOERROR;
        }

        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    if (dwError)
    {
        DbgPrint("<%S> err = %u\n", FileName, dwError);
    }

    goto __return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is actually the confusion brought to you by `goto label`.If you are using the recursive version, after the recursive execution is completed, it will return to the recursive place to continue execution.

In your code, you continue to execute `while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))`, but when you use `goto label`, it will jump out of the original loop and restart the program from the label, which leads to what you said `list a single directory tree before ending.`

If you modify the modified code to the following iterative version, you can understand why there is such a problem.

```
void fun()
{
    char* Directory = "D:\\test";
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    char SearchName[1024], FullPath[1024];
    char LastName[1024] = "";
    while (1)
    {
        memset(SearchName, 0, sizeof(SearchName));
        memset(&FindData, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

        sprintf(SearchName, "%s\\*", Directory);
        if (strcmp(SearchName, LastName) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        strcpy(LastName, SearchName);
        hFind = FindFirstFile(SearchName, &FindData);

        if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))
            {
                if (FindData.cFileName[0] == '.')
                {
                    continue;
                }

                memset(FullPath, 0, sizeof(FullPath));


                sprintf(FullPath, "%s\\%s", Directory, FindData.cFileName);

                if (FindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                    MessageBoxA(NULL, Directory, "Directory", MB_OK);
                    char cArray[1024];
                    memset(cArray, 0, sizeof(cArray));
                    sprintf(cArray, "%s", FullPath);
                    Directory = cArray;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBoxA(NULL, FullPath, "File", MB_OK);
                }
            }
            FindClose(hFind);
        }
    }
}
```

So you cannot achieve the same purpose as recursion by using `goto`, here you can only use recursion. Of course, I have provided a way to traverse directories non-recursively using queues, which is a more scientific way.

Comment: your code is same wrong as original. you anyway overwrite `hFind` variable.

Comment: @RbMm I know this code is wrong, I just modified it to an iterative version to make it clearer where the error is.

Comment: @RbMm And how to traverse the directory through iterative version, I have already answered in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386581/how-can-you-iterate-though-directories-without-using-any-recursive-functions-in/63387205#63387205).

Comment: that code anyway wrong in several places. again look only for `handle` - you open it in loop **multiple** times (`handle = FindFirstFile`) but close it only **once**. `Link`, `Queue` etc - nit need. exist more simply and correct solution

Comment: @RbMm Yes, in any case, the original code is problematic and should be implemented using recursion or queues (stacks, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

One of the key things that you obtain from recursion is a separate set of local variables for each call to the recursive function.  When a function calls itself, and in the recursive call modifies local variables, those local-variable changes do not (directly) affect the local variables of the caller.  In your original program, this applies to variables `hFind`, `FindData`, `SearchName`, and `FullPath`.

If you want similar behavior in a non-recursive version of the function then you need to *manually* preserve the state of your traversal of one level of the tree when you descend to another level.  The `goto` statement doesn't do any such thing -- it just redirects the control flow of your program.  Although there are a few good use cases for `goto` in C, they are uncommon, and yours is not one of them.

There are several ways to implement manually preserving state, but I would suggest

1. creating a structure type in which to store those data that characterize the state of your traversal of a particular level.  Those appear to be only `hFind` and `FindData` -- it looks like the other locals don't need to be preserved.  Maybe something like this, then:

   ```
   struct dir_state {
       HANDLE hFind;
       WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
   };
   ```
2. Dynamically allocating an array of structures of that type.

   ```
   unsigned depth_limit = DEFAULT_DEPTH_LIMIT;
   struct dir_state *traversal_states
           = malloc(depth_limit * sizeof(*traversal_states));
   if (traversal_states == NULL) // ... handle allocation error ...
   ```
3. Tracking the depth of your tree traversal, and for each directory you process, using the array element whose index is the relative depth of that directory.

   ```
   // For example:
   traversal_states[depth].hFind
           = FindFirstFile(SearchName, &traversal_states[depth].FindData);
   // etc.
   ```
4. Remembering the size of the array, so as to be able to reallocate it larger if the traversal descends too deep for its current size.

   ```
   // For example:
   if (depth >= depth_limit) {
       depth_limit = depth_limit * 3 / 2;
       struct dir_state *temp
           = realloc(traversal_states, depth_limit * sizeof(*traversal_states));
       if (temp == NULL) {
           // handle error, discontinuing traversal
       }
       traversal_states = temp;
   }
   ```

Also, use an ordinary `for`, `while`, or `do` loop instead of a backward-jumping `goto`.  There will be a few details to work out to track when to use `FindFirstFile` and when `FindNextFile` (which you would still have with `goto`), but I'm sure you can sort it out.

Details are left as an exercise.

Comment: @HenryJones, I'm sorry, but I have no basis on which to advise you regarding your current code, which presumably is fairly different from your original, nor am I particularly inclined at the moment to serve as a free coding service.  If you think your current code could serve as the basis of a question meaningfully different from this one, then you could consider posting such a question.

Answer (score -1):

Unless necessary due to memory or processing constraints or infinite recursion tail conditions that would be complication to introduce there really isn't much need to not use recursion here, since it leads to a readable and elegant solution.

I also want to point out that in "modern" C, any solution using a GOTO is likely not a solution you want since they are so often confusing to use and leads to memory issues (we have loops now to make all of that so much simpler).

Instead of the GOTOs I would suggest implementing a stack of the directories. Wrap the printing logic a while or do-while, and as you are iterating over the files add any directories to the stack. At every new iteration pop and walk the directory at the head of the stack. The loop condition just needs to check if the directory stack is empty, before continuing its block.

Comment: Recursion is one of those things that will **always** present an opportunity for a vulnerability. Recursion depth is near impossible to control, which makes it a prime candidate for a stack overflow. All the more since stack space is ever so scarce. Making this vulnerability exploitable from the outside by providing a specially crafted filesystem topology is all the more reason not. Bottom line: Whenever you think that recursion is a useful tool invest some more time into your education.